# How to optmize functions to speed up code block?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote following code which works extremly slowly. Some reasons are clear - huge amount of data and lack of any optimization in term of algorithms. But I think I missed some reasons connected with VBA specific.

Is it possible to speed up this code by optimization VBA specific things like which functions I use, i.e. with out algoritms optimization which looks like a heavy task.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim lastRowInResultTable As Long
    lastRowInResultTable = Sheets("result").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lastRowISourceTable As Long
    lastRowISourceTable = Sheets("cleared").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim userName As String
    
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer

    For i = 2 To 11 'lastRowInResultTable
        
        userName = Sheets("result").Cells(i, "A")
             
        For j = 2 To lastRowISourceTable
        
            Dim month As Integer
            Dim duration As Integer
            Dim counter As Integer
            counter = 0
        
            If Sheets("cleared").Cells(j, "H") = userName Then
                month = Sheets("cleared").Cells(j, "K")
                duration = Sheets("cleared").Cells(j, "L")
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
            
            Select Case month
                Case 10
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "B") = duration
                Case 11
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "C") = duration
                Case 12
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "D") = duration
                Case 1
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "E") = duration
                Case 2
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "F") = duration
                Case 3
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "G") = duration
                Case 4
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "H") = duration
                Case 5
                    Sheets("result").Cells(i, "I") = duration
            End Select
            
        Next j
                
    Next i
    
    t = Timer - t
    MsgBox t


End Sub
```

I tried to think about algoritms optimization to desrease number of cycle interation, but it looks like heavy task for me, which take many hours.

Comment: You should work with arrays: You can read the source data from the sheet to an array - and you can keep the results in another array. At the end you write the result array to the sheet. That will be much faster. Just search for "Excel vba range array" and you will find a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Can't you do this with a formula?

Comment: Try to add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the begining of code, and set them to `true` at the end of code, that will speed up the code very much. Also use the number instead of "A" in cells(i, "A") --> cells(i, 1)

Comment: There are some wrongs in the code. All `Dim` should be in the beginning of code, or at least outside of the loop. Also the `If Sheets("cleared").Cells(j, "H") = userName Then` should include `Select Case month` because "duration" will be empty otherwise.

Comment: @Loveb thanks! Your recomendation .ScreenUpdating and .EnableEvents helped to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

### A VBA Lookup

[image]

```vb
Sub LookupUsers()
    
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Cleared"
    Const SRC_USER_FIRST_CELL As String = "H2"
    Const SRC_MONTH_COLUMN As String = "K"
    Const SRC_DURATION_COLUMN As String = "L"
    Dim sMonths(): sMonths = VBA.Array(10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Result"
    Const DST_USER_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_DURATION_FIRST_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Dim dMonths(): dMonths = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_USER_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data in source.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim suData(), smData(), sdData()
    
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim suData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): suData(1, 1) = srg.Value
        ReDim smData(1 To 1, 1 To 1):
        smData(1, 1) = srg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_MONTH_COLUMN).Value
        ReDim sdData(1 To 1, 1 To 1):
        sdData(1, 1) = srg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_DURATION_COLUMN).Value
    Else
        suData = srg.Value
        smData = srg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_MONTH_COLUMN).Value
        sdData = srg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_DURATION_COLUMN).Value
    End If
    
    Dim srDict As Object: Set srDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    srDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sUser As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sUser = suData(sr, 1)
        If Len(sUser) > 0 Then
            If Not srDict.Exists(sUser) Then
                srDict(sUser) = sr
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If srDict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No valid data in source.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim scDict As Object: Set scDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sc As Long
    
    For sc = 0 To UBound(sMonths)
        scDict(sMonths(sc)) = dMonths(sc)
    Next sc
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    
    Dim drg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.Range(DST_USER_FIRST_CELL)
        drCount = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If drCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data in destination.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount)
    End With
    
    Dim duData()
    
    If drCount = 1 Then
        ReDim duData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): duData(1, 1) = drg.Value
    Else
        duData = drg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(sMonths) + 1
    
    Dim ddData(): ReDim ddData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim sMonth, dr As Long, dUser As String
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dUser = duData(dr, 1)
        If srDict.Exists(dUser) Then
            sr = srDict(dUser)
            sMonth = smData(sr, 1)
            If IsNumeric(sMonth) Then
                If scDict.Exists(sMonth) Then
                    ddData(dr, scDict(sMonth)) = sdData(sr, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next dr
    
    Dim ddrg As Range:
    Set ddrg = drg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_DURATION_FIRST_COLUMN)
    
    With ddrg.Resize(, dcCount)
        .Value = ddData
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
    End With
    

    t = Timer - t
    
    MsgBox "The lookup has finished in " & Format(t, "0.0000") & " seconds.", _
        vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, (maybe it's faster) :
The code assumed that the username in column A of sheet "result" are unique. So there is **no duplicate value in column A of sheet "result"**.

```
Sub test()
t = Timer
Dim rg As Range, cell As Range, rgM As Range, m As Range
Dim txt As String, pos As Integer, col As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rg = Sheets("result").UsedRange
Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
txt = ",10-B,11-C,12-D,1-E,2-F,3-G,4-H,5-i"

For Each cell In rg
If Not Sheets("cleared").Columns("H").Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("cleared").Columns("H")
        .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rgM = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 3)
        .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With

    For Each m In rgM
        pos = InStr(txt, "," & m & "-")
        If pos <> 0 Then
            If Len(m.Value) = 1 Then col = Mid(txt, pos + 3, 1) Else col = Mid(txt, pos + 4, 1)
            Sheets("result").Cells(cell.Row, col).Value = m.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

rg variable is the range of username in column A sheet "result".
It create a string as txt variable contains the identification for the month and the column.

Then it loop to each cell in rg, create the range of all rows which value is the looped cell (the username) in column H sheet "cleared" as rgM variable.

Then it loop within rgM to get the month as m variable, then check the identification for the column by using instr of the txt value as col variable, then write it to sheet "result" using the cell.row and the col.

I don't test it with many data... but I hope it's faster because the sub doesn't check each cell in column H of sheet "cleared".

Test it with the same data, your code took 1.132813, and the sub above took 0.2890625 ... but I think Mr. VBasic's code is much faster (haven't test it yet).

The thing which still I'm not sure is the username in column A in sheet "result", are they unique ? or are there duplicate value ? If unique and if in sheet "cleared" there is a repeating month for the same username, do you need to sum the duration for the same month?

Before running the sub:
[image]

After running the sub: 
[image]